# How to check Customer login or not when we click on customer navigation tab magento2?

Tags: magento2

In Magento 1 if we create custom customer navigation link in that when we load page that time we check that customer is login or not if not than we redirect that page to login page using this code in controller

```
public function preDispatch()
{
    parent::preDispatch();

    if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->authenticate($this)) {
        $this->setFlag('', 'no-dispatch', true);
    }
}
```

In Magento 2 How can i check this if customer is not login than redirect to login page???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Your Controller

```
namespace Company\Module\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface; //use this
class .....{
     public function __construct(
        .....
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        .....
     ){
         ....
         $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
         ....

     }
     public function dispatch(RequestInterface $request)
     {
          if (!$this->customerSession->authenticate()) {
              $this->_actionFlag->set('', self::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
          }
          return parent::dispatch($request);
     }
         ....

}
```

In Magento 2 We can do that using this code

Comment: This is i m looking for

Comment: I also getting this issue, can you please let me know in which controller i am adding this code?

Answer (score 0):

Following code you can check customer login or not anywhere

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
   // customer login action
}
```

From controller

```
$this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
   // customer login action
}
```

**I hope this will help you.**